# Open Xamarin.Mac project in Visual Studio on PC without attaching to Mac

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.mac

I have a VS solution which contains a Xamarin.Mac project. On my Mac, it works just fine. On my PC, when I open the solution, I always see the following window:

[image]

Right off, this is annoying; it would be much more pleasant to be prompted for a Mac if/when I try to build on Mac.

But it's worse than that. When I hit Close, because I don't have a Mac handy at the moment, it then says the Mac project is unloadable.

I don't want to build or run. I just want to look at the code, do project-wide searches, and so on. I can always open an individual file by navigating there in File Explorer. But that's much less efficient than using the project navigator.

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Mac application or Library?

Comment: it's an application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio for Windows it's not supporting Xamarin.Mac, it supports only Xamarin.Ios. That's why visual studio can't load the Xamarin.Mac project.
If you would like to develop applications for Osx using Xamarin you can do that only on a Mac.

Comment: It is what I is I guess . . . it's unfortunate that "unsupported" means "I can't open the project" rather than "I can't build the project, and code completion won't work."

Comment: Usually when I want on windows to view a xamarin.mac project/code and just edit it a bit without compiling, I use Visual Studio Code. It has also code completion for C#.

Comment: Visual Studio does support "limited" building of Xamarin.Mac Library projects, if they do not require native references for example. However, it is impossible to build a macOS bundle without invoke clang on a mac. I do agree that the popup is annoying though, let me file a bug...https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50271